# Measuring distance between two points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I have two shapefiles and I would like to know the distance between each point on File1 and each corresponding point on File2 (one to one relationship).

I have been using the Ruler and manually calculating this, but is there a more efficient way?

I am able to produce one table with the lat/long from Table 1 and the lat/long from Table 2. However, I do not know how to populate a distance column with an equation (and I do not know Python).

Comment: if you have ArcInfo, you can use the Near tool.  Otherwise, some basic geometry with the coordinates works too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggesting the Near tool. I am familiarizing myself with it right now. However, it does not appear to measure distances between pairs of points (based on a unique #). Rather, what I desire to do is determine the lengths between one point in File1 and one point in File2 (A1 to B1, A2 to B2, A3 to B3).

Comment: Look into the Point Distance tool (requires Advanced license). This provides distances between all possible pairs of points.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm really looking for a 1:1 relationship based on a unique ID, so this does not work.

Comment: While Point distance would give you all possible pairings of points, it's a simple enough matter to filter/definition query/select records in the result only where ID1 = ID2. That would get you the distances only between matched pairs of points. @phloem should probably make an answer out of that.

Answer (score 2):

As commented under the OP, my suggestion is to use the [Point Distance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001r000000) geoprocessing tool, if you have Advanced licensing.

1. Run Point Distance tool to calculate the distance between all possible combinations of points
2. [Start editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m500000003000000)
3. [Select by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) where ID1 <> ID2
4. [Delete the selected records](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000016000000)

Answer (score 0):

If you points have unique ID's that you are trying to measure between:

1. Point to Line tool
2. Line field being the unique ID of the matching points
3. Add length field to the lines output for the units you need.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am doing this wrong, but when attempting to use the Points to Line feature, it appears I must connect all the points in File 1 together. Rather, what I want to do is determine the lengths between one point in File1 and one point in File2 (A1 to B1, A2 to B2, A3 to B3). I am looking to measure the distance between each pair of points. Any ideas?

Comment: @WolverineTime A possible workaround to enable PolyGeo's answer is to add a new field to your two point files and populate it with A for all records in one file and B for all records in the other, then merge/append the two files together. With all points in a single file, this method will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the XY to line tool and then midpoint the resulting line.

The way I do it is ...

1. Ensure your points in file1 and file2 are tagged with a matching identifying attribute for each vertice eg: VertexID
2. Calculate geometry (or Xtools) to create a latitude and longitude field for both file1 and file2
3. Join File1 and File2 on VertexID so you now have coordinates for file 1 & 2 in the same table
4. Export the table
5. Use the table in the 'XY to line' tool to create a line between the points for each vertex (http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012092)
6. Create a midpoint from the line using Xtools (centroid tool, easy) or this slightly clunky ESRI procedure that achieves that same. http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012326